# Install windows service on different computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I was trying to follow [this tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816169):

Which said:

> "Click Setup and Deployment Projects under Project Types, and then
>   click *Setup Project* under Templates."

But in my VS2012 - there is no `Setup Project`:

[image: screenshot]

So I am confused what to do?

ps. **What is the easiest way to install a Windows service on a different computer?** (I don't like the idea of using tool which has steep learning curve for this task).

pps. **Can't I manually use `installUtil` to install the windows service say on the target machine?** What are caveats with this approach??

Comment: why downvote? I showed what I did so far. And asked a clear question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create MSI or setup Project with visual studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378125/create-msi-or-setup-project-with-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: @Micke: That is not necessarily duplicate - there might be other ways to install service on different machine than using installer - that is what I also asked here; and that question is not about services

Comment: You might be correct, but have a look at the accepted answer anyway. It'll tell you that the limited installer cannot be used to install a service, and provides info on what to use instead.

Comment: @Micke: Ah so I can't use that installer to install a Windows Service?

Comment: Yes you can use installutil to install the service. If this is an in-house project it's the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Visual Studio setup projects (vdproj) will not ship with future versions of VS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx).

[WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/main/wix_learning.html) is a good alternative and has a quite steep learning curve. Checkout this [sample](http://www.talksharp.com/wix-toolset-install-windows-service).

Comment: learning curve doesn't sound nice now-isn't there some easier alternative? maybe manually install the service on target machine?

Answer (score 0):

I recently hit this issue as well. 
If you can get on the machine via remote desktop then you can run "InstallUtil" and point it at your service executable:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe c:\path\to\my\service.exe
```

If you can't remote into the machine then there are tools such as PsExec https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx which will allow you to run applications on remote machines. You might be able to use this to run InstallUtil on the remote server.

The method I used was to run "service controller" with something like this:

```
sc.exe \\myserver create "My Service Name" binpath= c:\path\to\my\service.exe
```

There's some more information on it here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990289.aspx
There's also a bunch of flags you can use to set up all the parameters of a service e.g. what action to take if it stops.

Comment: what about `installutil`? Can't I use that? It would be easier than using a tool I guess. What are caveats with `installutil`?

Comment: I think I got my answer wrong a little bit about installutil, you don't need a setup project for it, I think you can just point it at the service executable. I've updated my answer.

Comment: are you suggesting something like in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599562/how-can-i-install-a-windows-service-onto-a-machine-that-doesnt-have-visual-stud. But must the target machine also have .net framework for this? and must the version of .net framework on the target machine match the .net framework version where the service was built?

Comment: Yes that looks basically the same as what I'm saying. The target machine will need the .net framework installed to do this (but then if your service uses .net then you'd need it just to run). You might be able to get away with using an older framework version of InstallUtil but you'd be best off using the latest/a version matching your assembly.

Comment: Ok that seems only alternative now? The only trick is now whether those .net framework versions should match or not

Comment: Looks like this might be the answer you were looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564467/can-installutil-be-used-to-install-a-service-written-with-a-newer-version-of-the

Comment: So they say the versions must match? I will give a try anyway maybe I can get away with it; btw. is it lot of work to update newer version of .net framework on target machine?

Comment: It shouldn't be a lot of work. You should just be able to download and run the installers straight off e.g. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30653 You might find you need to update "windows installer" or chain the updates e.g. install .Net 3, then .Net 4 then... but it's not complex or particularly time consuming.

Comment: Maybe I can get away with older version of `installUtil` .. otherwise I need to update as I see.. there seems no other option?

Comment: Does Visual Studio need to be installed on target machine to use `installUtil` if you know? thanks

Comment: No I don't think you need VS. It should just come with the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MsDeploy to deploy a windows service. We did it recently in our project, you can find a tutorial [here](http://www.jamescrowley.co.uk/2011/09/05/deploying-windows-services-using-msdeploy/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the time/scope, worth checking out [Topshelf](http://topshelf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html). It makes building and deploying Windows Services ridiculously easy, with no need for messy setup projects/installers. It just becomes a case of calling `myservice.exe install` or `myservice.exe uninstall` (plus any credentials if needed). This can be triggered remotely or as Tasker suggested, using sc or psexec.

Comment: what about the `installutil` tool? what are the caveats with it?

Comment: You won't need to use intallutil in that case, have a read of [this](http://topshelf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview/faq.html).

Comment: Yes but I have already created my service, this thing asks me to create a new service using TopShelf?

Comment: Why not use `installutil ` if it can solve my problem? Just I read somewhere some .Net framework versions must be same of installUtil and service that is what I am tryign to figure out now

Comment: Yes it should do the trick if this is a one-off install. Easiest to get the service files on the remote machine, then register the service with installutil or sc (just watch out for [caveats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692250/installing-windows-service-with-sc-exe-or-installutil-exe-there-is-difference)). My answer may be of longer term help if a) maintenance and deployment of the service will be on-going and b) you have the time. Depending on complexity, the service logic should be very straightforward to port across. If so, IMO it's worth the effort if you can...

Comment: I think I can use `installUtil` just I think the .NET versions must match on target machine and where the service was built... I am figuring that out now